# ChoiseBox JavaFX doesn't display a data

Tags: java, javafx

I need help. I have a fxml file with scene with button, tableview, etc. In controller there is a method for one of ChoiseBox, but i can't see a data on this one after building.
I tried do another controller, another method, but no one way helps me

ChoiseBox is with id - monthChoiceBox

FXML

```
<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
       <Button layoutX="449.0" layoutY="15.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Открыть" />
       <ChoiceBox fx:id="monthChoiceBox" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="247.0" />
       <Button layoutX="1162.0" layoutY="626.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Сохранить" />
       <ChoiceBox layoutX="278.0" layoutY="16.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
     </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller

```
// some import classes

public class Controller {

    @FXML private ChoiceBox<String> monthChoiceBox;

    @FXML
    private void fillmonthChoiceBox() {
        ObservableList<String> month = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        month.addAll("Январь", "Февраль", "Март",
                "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь",
                "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь",
                "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");
        monthChoiceBox.setItems(month);

    }
}
```

Main

```
package sample;

//some import classes
public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Учет рабочего времени дежурно-диспетчерского состава");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a call of fillmonthChoiceBox(). @FXM Annotation for method is used for binding handlers for component. Like onMouseClicked="#handleOnMouseClicked". In this case could be used @FXML public void initialize() {} for data init